# Counting four-digit numbers with repeating digits

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, fractions

> Of all the four-digit positive integers containing only digits from the set $\{2,4,6,8\}$, what fraction of them have at least one of their digits repeating?

Express your answer as a fraction.

I'm having trouble with this exercise.

Can someone help me get started?

Comment: @rene I think the caps lock is mainly due to his problem being more important than everybody else's!!

Comment: In those cases wher "at least" is asked, it is always helpful to consider also the opposite case, here the set of numbers with no repeating digits.

Comment: @Chinny84 haha no i don't think that and im not a he btw

Answer (score 2):

Usual tricks to get started for any problem

- Try a simpler problem
- Try brute-force calculation
- Look for other problems that this one resembles

Have you any ideas on how to do any of these three things?

For counting problems in particular, one trick that is:

- Try counting the complement: how many things are there in all, and how many *aren't* the kind of thing you're looking for?

If you are having any troubles at all, it's nearly always worth at least writing down the complementary problem to see if it offers any inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

All the $4$-digit numbers with digits among $\{2,4,6,8\}$ are $4^4=256$. All those which do not repeat digits are $4!=24$. So those with at least one repetition are $4^4-4!=232$. Their fraction is hence
$$
\frac{232}{256}.
$$